# What does "in areas" distinguish in Atlas passives?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've been getting some Atlas passives from Maven. Almost all passives contain the qualifier "in areas". What does this mean exactly? I have the following guesses:

- In maps only
- Not campaign or boss fights, like Maven herself
- Only that section of the Atlas, like Heawark Hamlet
- Maps that have the corresponding master mission active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the quadrant that the passive tree belongs to. For instance, take [Lira Arthain](https://www.poewiki.net/w/images/1/1a/Lira_Arthain.png) for example. If you were to take Distinguished Demolitionist, you gain 35% increased Explosive Radius and 20% increased number of Explosives in maps that belong to Lira Arthain.